# Track messages sent to nodes in a Cluster

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

If there are *n*-nodes in a Cluster and I am routing some messages to them, is there a way to track which message has been sent to which node from within the Cluster Router(RoundRobinPool or any other if available).

i.e After sending all the messages, at last, I need a list something like..
'message-1,4,7 has been sent to A-node',
'message-2,5,8 to B-node',
'message-3,6,9 to C-node' and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to get this information is to have the receiving actor on the other end of the router send an acknowledgement message back to the original sender and then log that on the sending side. You could also turn some of the logging tools for logging remote message sending on or off, but that will be verbose.

https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka.Remote/Configuration/Remote.conf#L125

Comment: Is there any possibility of bringing the new feature of tracking the sent messages without sending an acknowledgment in the future version of Akka.Net. It will be nice to see such a feature.